# Combine 2 enums with math operators

Tags: c, enums

I have this enums:

```
enum bus {
    MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN, 
    MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL = 1 << 1,
    MEDIA_BUS_PCI = 1 << 2,
    MEDIA_BUS_USB = 1 << 3,
};
```

and:

```
enum bus get_bus( char *sys )
{
    FILE *fd;
    char file[PATH_MAX];
    char s[1024];

    if(!strcmp(sys, "/sys/devices/virtual"))
        return MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL;

    snprintf(file, PATH_MAX, "%s/modalias", sys);
    fd = fopen(file, "r");
    if(!fd)
        return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
    if(!fgets(s, sizeof(s), fd)) {
        fclose(fd);
        return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
    }
    fclose(fd);

    if(!strncmp(s, "pci", 3))
        return MEDIA_BUS_PCI;
    if(!strncmp(s, "usb", 3))
        return MEDIA_BUS_USB;

    return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
```

}

I want to create a function to return device(s) with pci or usb bus:

```
const char *get_device(const enum bus desired_bus)
{
    enum bus bus;
...................................................
    for( i = 0; i < md->md_size; i++, md_ptr++ ) {
        bus = get_bus( md_ptr->sys );
        if( ( bus & desired_bus ) == desired_bus )
                return md_ptr->node;
}
```

and call this function to return device(s):

```
get_device(const enum bus desired_bus)
```

if request is for devices with pci or usb bus type:

```
get_device(MEDIA_BUS_PCI | MEDIA_BUS_USB);
```

It is possible to use math operators for enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can use math operators, but I believe you're looking for [**bitwise operations**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C), right?. In this case, you `enum` members values need to be power of two, sou you will be able to do test like this: `if(desired_bus & MEDIA_BUS_PCI)` if a previously `desired_bus |= MEDIA_BUS_PCI` was done the `if` will have `MEDIA_BUS_PCI` value, so `if` is `true` meaning the bit is set.

code example:

```
enum bus {
    MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN, 
    MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL = 1 << 1,
    MEDIA_BUS_PCI = 1 << 2,
    MEDIA_BUS_USB = 1 << 3,
};
/* set flags */
desired_bus |= (MEDIA_BUS_PCI | MEDIA_BUS_USB);

and then:

        /* test if flag MEDIA_BUS_PCI was requested.. */
       if(desired_bus & MEDIA_BUS_PCI)
```

In case of it is not set, we get a 0 value that match to our `MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN` value that I think that is a nice to mean error.

**EDIT** A more complete working C example:

```
enum bus {
    MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN, 
    MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL = 1 << 1,
    MEDIA_BUS_PCI = 1 << 2,
    MEDIA_BUS_USB = 1 << 3,
};

enum bus get_bus( const char *sys );

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    const char *sym = argv[1];
    enum bus b = get_bus(sym);

    if(b & MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL)
        printf("MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL requested\n");
    if(b & MEDIA_BUS_USB)
        printf("MEDIA_BUS_USB requested\n");
    return 0;
}

enum bus get_bus( const char *sys )
{
    if(!strcmp("pci", sys))
        return MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL;
    if(!strcmp("usb", sys))
        return MEDIA_BUS_USB;
    if(!strcmp("pci&usb", sys))
        return MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL | MEDIA_BUS_USB;
    return MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN;
}
```

If you invoke the compiled program with:

`a.exe usb:` will output:

`MEDIA_BUS_USB requested`

`a.exe "pci&usb"` will output:

```
MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL requested
MEDIA_BUS_USB requested
```

NOTE: You might need to use a type like `unsigned` instead of `enum bus` (that highest size is `int`) to hold a set of `enum bus` values.

Comment: when set desired_bus to MEDIA_BUS_PCI | MEDIA_BUS_USB and check: if((bus & desired_bus) == desired_bus) to get output if bus is pci or usb, not work.

Comment: @user935420: Post the code that actually you have used(including your enum definiton). But the `desired_bus` in your code in this comment must be one-of enum values.

Comment: @user935420: You need to do individual check. One per time. Check out new code example

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *but* for your case, you'll want to make sure that each combination of enum-values is unique, and easily decomposed. To do this, you should make each one a distinct power of two:

```
enum bus {
    MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN = 1,
    MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL = 2,
    MEDIA_BUS_PCI = 4,
    MEDIA_BUS_USB = 8,
};
```

(You can then test for a match by writing e.g. `desired_bus & MEDIA_BUS_PCI`.)

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal taste, but I find using enums to hold bitmasks rather misleading.

I would rather do it with `#define`s, to be able to define mask combinations easily. For instance:

```
#define MEDIA_BUS_UNKNOWN 0x00

#define MEDIA_BUS_GPU     0x10
#define MEDIA_BUS_CPU     0x20

#define MEDIA_BUS_VIRTUAL (0x1 | MEDIA_BUS_CPU)
#define MEDIA_BUS_PCI     (0x2 | MEDIA_BUS_CPU)
#define MEDIA_BUS_USB     (0x3 | MEDIA_BUS_CPU)
#define MEDIA_BUS_AGP     (0x4 | MEDIA_BUS_GPU)
#define MEDIA_BUS_PCIE    (0x5 | MEDIA_BUS_GPU)

#define MEDIA_BUS_PU_MASK   0x30 // to isolate the PU type 
#define MEDIA_BUS_TYPE_MASK 0x0F // to isolate the bus type 

typedef int bus_type;
```

(a rather silly example, but I could not find better without straying too far from the OP's question)